# Pound symbol (£) on US keyboard on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, keyboard

I need a shortcut to make a pound symbol with a US keyboard in 12.10.

The only way I can make one is by holding control-shift and typing u00a3.  Too much typing for a single symbol!

I'm using GNOME classic.

Comment: can you check whether [the ubuntu ComposeKey docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) help you?

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>ComposeKey</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>

(<kbd>-</kbd> on the main keyboard not the number pad)

£

See... it works

Comment: That's assuming that OP enabled the compose key.

Comment: for those who don't know what ComposeKey is, go to gnome tweaks->Keyboard & mouse->Compose Key->Enable it and set your desired key.

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key#US_international), AltGr + Shift + 4 should be the standard shortcut.