# How can symbols like €, £ and other special characters be typed briskly in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: keyboard, unicode

How can special characters (like €, £ and others) be typed briskly in Ubuntu 16.04 (set in US English and with a UK keyboard)? I have seen instructions online for previous versions of Ubuntu but these don't seem to be working.

The approach I have currently is the following:

- €: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- £: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

some examples of things that aren't a solution for me:

- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> -- not working ([reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/238027/pound-symbol-%C2%A3-on-us-keyboard-on-12-10))
- set option *Adding currency signs to certain keys* -- no such option ([reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397322/typing-british-pound-sign-ubuntu-13-10-spanish-keyboard-layout))
- use Character Map -- awkward non-keypress solution ([reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624608/unable-to-type-symbol-like-%C2%A3-and-alike))

Comment: With the *English (UK)* keyboard you should be able to type **£** as `Shift+3` as you can check by yourself with the **Keyboard Layout Chart**

Comment: @M.Becerra Thanks for your suggestion. The system is set in US English, so using the UK keyboard for `Shift`+`3` results in `#` while `Shift`+`4` results in `$`.

Comment: You can run the `Text Entry` application and switch your keyboard layout to the `English (UK)` layout. It also contains a way to switch between layouts with a key combination if you want more than one layout.